# How can I modify a python dictionary of arrays/lists in place without doubling memory consumption?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a dictionary with numpy arrays as values. I want to modify these arrays by adding one extra element at the end. Because numpy arrays are not suitable for this, I first convert the arrays into lists, and then add a value p to the end.

However, when I run this function, memory consumption is doubled, as if the arrays were copied, instead of being modified in place.

Here is the code:

```
def add_coordinates(my_Dict):
  n = 0
  for key in my_Dict.keys():
    # Convert values of each key to a list. In place?
    my_Dict[key] = [list(s) for s in my_Dict[key]]    
    del s
    for index in range(len(my_Dict[key])):
      p = [float(index)/len(my_Dict[key])]      
      my_Dict[key][index] = my_Dict[key][index] + p
    my_Dict[key] = np.array(my_Dict[key])
  return my_Dict
```

After a suggestion to create a new numpy array with the extended dimension and then append the new value, I modified the code like this:

```
def add_coordinates(my_Dict):
  for key in my_Dict.keys():
    tmp = np.zeros((my_Dict[key].shape[0],my_Dict[key].shape[1]+1))
    tmp[:,:-1] = my_Dict[key]
    for index in range(len(my_Dict[key])):
      tmp[index,-1] = float(index)/len(my_Dict[key])
    my_Dict[key] = tmp
  return my_Dict
```

As a third option, I use np.concatenate to add the new dimension to th numpy arrays:

```
def add_coordinates(my_Dict):
  for key in my_Dict.keys():
    coords = np.zeros((my_Dict[key].shape[0],1))
    for index in range(my_Dict[key].shape[0]):
      coords[index] = float(index)/my_Dict[key].shape[0]
    my_Dict[key] = np.concatenate((my_Dict[key],coords),axis=1)
  return my_Dict
```

But np.concatenate also makes a copy.

All of these options double memory requirements. Is there any way to do this without making copies of the original arrays, and do all modifications in place?

Comment: When you convert to lists you are making a copy of the data, for starters

Comment: Why don't you replace your numpy array with the new array in place i.e create a array with n+1 values and my_dict[i]= newarray

Comment: @NiteyaShah I tried that (included code in the question), but creating a new numpy array to replace the old one does not seem to remove the old one from memory...

Comment: This looks like a possible use case for `numpy.append`.

Comment: @user2357112 numpy.append also generates a copy.. same as numpy.insert

Comment: @hirschme: Yes, but it does far less copying than what you're doing now.

Comment: This is an intrinsic issue of all languages that have garbage collection , and I don't think there is any suggested way to delete objects from memory , the only two things i can think of now are  weak referencing https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#example and keeping large numpy array by default and instead of growing it , just replace by index , but I believe this isn't very memory efficient . Python 's object reference will almost always create duplicates , if this is major issue then maybe implement this part of the code in C? It will certainly be a nice performance boost